# Is it possible to hide the dock icon programmatically

Tags: cocoa, macos, user-agent, nib

Is it possible to hide dock icon programmatically on demand. I know one way by which defining property "Application is agent (UIElement)" in plist we make the cocoa app as user agent. But this result in hiding the dock icon permanently.

I am looking for a way where i can control visibility of dock icon. Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately not. You can transform a background-only app to a foreground app using the `TransformProcessType()` function but you can't go from a foreground app to a background app.

Here's how to go from background to foreground:

```
ProcessSerialNumber psn = { 0, kCurrentProcess }; 
OSStatus returnCode = TransformProcessType(&psn, kProcessTransformToForegroundApplication);
if( returnCode != 0) {
    NSLog(@"Could not bring the application to front. Error %d", returnCode);
}
```

Comment: Ohh..
is it possible to control visibility of main menu programmatically ? If i can do that then i might have solution. ?

Comment: Unicorn: It is on Mac OS X 10.6: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/KioskMode/ On older versions of Mac OS X, you can use `SetSystemUIMode` with the `kUIModeAllHidden` option, as described in TN2062: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2002/tn2062.html but that solution will also hide the Dock (not just your Dock tile—*the whole Dock*).

Comment: Yes I tried that, but its not what I need. If this is technical limitation then i shld figure some other way out... Thanks for ur help guys !

Answer (score 5):

It is possible. However, it also hides the menu.

```
NSApplication.shared.setActivationPolicy(.accessory)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
    NSApplication.shared.windows.first!.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
}
```

And back:

```
NSApplication.shared.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
```