# Hide Dock icon without closing window

Tags: macos, cocoa, dock

I am creating an app in which I want to give the user the ability to show or hide the dock icon at run time. I have a preferences window with a checkbox, setting a user default value, which fires the following code using KVO:

```
if (!hideDockIcon) {
    TransformProcessType(&psn, kProcessTransformToForegroundApplication);
} else {
    TransformProcessType(&psn, kProcessTransformToUIElementApplication);
}
```

This works, but when hiding, the preferences window is closed directly (which makes sense as it is now a background app). However, I noticed that MS's SkyDrive client manages to hide the icon while keeping the Preferences window open. I have not been able to find out how one would do that, anybody has an idea?

I also tried using `[NSApp setActivationPolicy: NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular]` and `NSApplicationActivationPolicyAccessory`/`NSApplicationActivationPolicyProhibited` but that doesn't work for me; `Accessory` doesn't hide the dock icon, `Prohibited` closes the window as well and seems to make `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES]` being ignored.

Comment: Look at the following answer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832961/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-dock-icon-programmatically

Comment: I have, and at these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=kProcessTransformToUIElementApplication, and that is what I already do as you can see in my question, but none go into keeping a window open when transforming the process type. Unless you refer to the KioskMode link in that thread, which is for hiding the whole dock, not just one icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I stumbled upon [this thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/284023-prevent-nswindow-from-hiding-with-app.html) where the following is suggested to prevent a window from being hidden:

```
[window setCanHide:NO];
```

This just covers hiding. If your window gets closed, you might try to use the window delegate?
There's a call that let's you prevent the window from being closed

```
- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender
```

Comment: `setCanHide` does the trick, thanks! I tried `windowShouldclose` earlier, but it seems that one isn't fired when setting UIElement.

Comment: Since you say, `setCanHide` works, the Applications just gets hidden and since the window in not closed the `windowShouldClose` delegate call isn't fired.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by not activating the app in the same run loop turn:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
});
```

Swift:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
    NSApp.activateIgnoringOtherApps(true)
}
```

I'm calling dispatch_async to schedule the block for execution in one of the next run loop turns a few nanoseconds later. This gives the process the chance to finish hiding itself.

Comment: This does result in a momentary flicker as the app re-activates but it does work.  For Swift 5 you would need to update it to `DispatchQueue.main.async { NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)}`